# UIViewController Storyboard custom size

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, storyboard, uikit, uistoryboard

I am planning to show a small settings menu which has few UISegmentControls and sliders. I don't want to show it full screen, just show it as a subview in my view controller. One way would be to define it as a subclass of UIView altogether but then all designing would have to be done in xib file rather than Storyboard. My questions:

1. What is the right approach here - UIViewController, UIView, or any of the two?
2. If we take UIViewController route, how do we design the view in storyboard with a custom size?

Comment: In storyboard you can imbed a uiviewcontroller in a container view. As far as 1 v 2 that is a personal choice.

Comment: How do you design view with custom size in Storyboard?

Comment: you don't need to do all the designing again just copy viewController's view and paste in XIB :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both the approaches are fine.

But I personally prefer to have `UIViewController`.

While designing ViewController in Storyboard, I make main view's background color to clear(or sometimes black color with alpha between 0 to 0.5); Now I add other subview inside main view with whatever size that i want.

Now while presenting given view controller, make sure that you are using `.overCurrentContext` for `modalPresentationStyle`.

Use code as

```
myVC?.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext;
self.present(myVC!, animated: false, completion: nil);
```

If you use different `modalPresentationStyle` then, your background will look pure black. But if you use `overCurrentContext`, then new view controller will be presented above current one, so, if you kept background color as clear then it will be transparent.